# Is there any restriction of new incoming/outgoing TCP connections/seconds in Windows?

Tags: windows, tcp, connection, restrictions

Is there any restriction of number of new incoming/outgoing TCP connections/seconds in Windows? If so, are there any differences between Windows versions?

Comment: Thx. And what about other Windows versions? And is this 'long time' defined as an exact value?

Answer (score 0):

Sorta. In WinXP SP2 and later you are limited as to the number of pending outgoing connection attempts. There is no limit on the number of connections in a certain time period; but if those connections take a 'long time' to connect then you will be limited in how fast you can establish them.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.12.network.aspx mentions TcpNumConnections in a registry location but I couldn't make this work on win 7 at least ? Anyone, a way to increase the concurrent connections limit (or at least number of newly opened sockets per second) ?